# API Error ORA-29270: too many open HTTP requests

Tags: plsql

We are getting the ORA-29270:too many open HTTP requests when try to execute the Below Procedure. Please let us know where and all we need to close the Request and Response , Please provide one of the Procedure example how we can handle the exception. and all the request should process Properly.

```
    BEGIN
  l_http_request := utl_http.begin_request (p_url, 'POST');

  BEGIN
    -- build the request by using utl_http.set_header() and utl_http.write_text()
    -- ...

    -- process the request and get the response:
    l_http_response := utl_http.get_response (l_http_request);
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
         --- utl_http.end_response(http_resp);
              error_code := '91'; 
            error_desc := SQLERRM  || ' Unhandled Exception'; 
  END;
  BEGIN
    LOOP
      -- read the response using utl_http.read_line()
      -- ...
    END LOOP;
    -- Complete the request and response, and close the network connection
    utl_http.end_response(l_http_response);

  EXCEPTION 
    when utl_http.end_of_body then
    utl_http.end_response(http_resp); 

    WHEN error_out THEN
        NULL;
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
       --- utl_http.end_response(http_resp);
            error_code := '91'; 
            error_desc := SQLERRM  || ' Unhandled Exception'; 
                      END;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello:  I happen to be addressing the same error in my own code.  I fixed mine by adding utl_http.end_response(l_http_response) - which you already have.

But I notice you use two different arguments in your end_response call.  Try changing

```
utl_http.end_response(http_resp);
```

to

```
utl_http.end_response(l_http_response);
```

in your exception block.  I hope this helps.  Cheers, Hawk